# ion content set starting position dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, ionic-framework

I have an ion content which scrolls on x axis and user can select a category. After selection it hides that content but unfortunately when i am showing the content again it fails to scroll to the preselected category.

```
<ion-content direction="x" class="wide-as-needed animate-show"  ng-show="showFilterStatus" style="float:left;width:100%;"
                         on-scroll="testSwipe()" scroll-event-interval="1000" has-bouncing="false"  delegate-handle="small" padding="false" >
                <ul class="hNav clearfix" style="width:800px;"> <!--style="width:500px;"-->
                    <!--<li ><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
                    <li ng-repeat="filter in filterList"><a ng-class="{sltItm: $index==showFilterSelected}" ng-click="changeFilter($index)">{{filter.filterType}}</a></li>-->
                    <li><img src="img/spacer.png" width="80" height="80" /></li>
                    <li ng-repeat="filter in fTest">
                        <img ng-src="{{filter.not_selected}}" width="80" height="80" ng-show="filSel != $index" ng-click="clickFilter($index)"/>
                        <img ng-src="{{filter.selected}}" width="80" height="80" ng-show="filSel == $index" ng-click="showFilter()"/>
                    </li>
                    <!--<li ><img src="img/spacer.png" width="80" height="80" /></li>-->
                </ul>

            </ion-content>
```

controller

```
$scope.filSel = 0;
$scope.showFilter = function(){

            //delegate.scrollTo(100*$scope.filSel, 0 , false);
            if ($scope.showFilterStatus == false){

                $scope.showFilterStatus = true;

                delegate.scrollTo(100*$scope.filSel, 0 , false);
            }
            else{
                $scope.showFilterStatus = false;

            }
        };

 $scope.clickFilter = function($index){
            if ($index == 4){
                $scope.showFilterDetail();
            }else{
                $scope.filSel = $index;
                startAtX = (100*$index);
                delegate.scrollTo(100*$scope.filSel,0,true);
                var time = $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.showFilterStatus = false;
                    return true;
                }, 1000);
            }


        };
```

Please help

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: It is not setting to the right position when user toggles the content. it sets to position 0